# Distinction between Larmor frequency and Rabi frequency

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, optics, atomic-physics

Wikipedia said

"In the context of a nuclear magnetic resonance experiment, the Rabi frequency is the nutation frequency of a sample's net nuclear magnetization vector about a radiofrequency field. (Note that this is distinct from the Larmor frequency, which characterizes the precession of a transverse nuclear magnetization about a static magnetic field.)"

However the two definitions seem equivalent to me... Any clarifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have a rough idea now. Rabi frequency is how hard you drive between the levels and Larmor frequency is how fast a state precesses. They corresponds to different directions(Rabi for rotation around any direction in the x-y plane and Larmor for rotations around the poles).